# Incorrect output from Ordered List Search algorithm

Tags: c, algorithm, search

I am implementing an ordered list search algorithm into my program. The search algorithm has to be an ordered list search algorithm. I can't switch to a binary search algorithm.

The code iterates through an index of 15 items, with each item an interval of 5 starting at 10. (EG 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, etc.)

The code reads in a target value from the user to be looked for in the index.

Here is the desired output:

```
Ordered Sequential Search:
    Array Index: [ 0][ 1][ 2][ 3][ 4][ 5][ 6][ 7][ 8][ 9][10][11][12][13][14]
     Array Data:  10  15  20  25  30  35  40  45  50  55  60  65  70  75  80
    User Target:  80
    Search Path: [ 0][ 1][ 2][ 3][ 4][ 5][ 6][ 7][ 8][ 9][10][11][12][13][14]
```

Where `Array Index` is the index printed using a loop, `Array Data` is the item at each index, `User Target` is the value inputted from the user, and `Search Path` is the path through the index that is taken by the algorithm. Everything else except `Search Path` is printed in other functions. I just included them because it helps visualize what is going wrong.

My code is not outputting as expected.

Here is my output using the same target value:

```
Ordered Sequential Search:
    Array Index: [ 0][ 1][ 2][ 3][ 4][ 5][ 6][ 7][ 8][ 9][10][11][12][13][14]
     Array Data:  10  15  20  25  30  35  40  45  50  55  60  65  70  75  80 
    User Target:  80
    Search Path: [ 0][ 1][ 2][ 3][ 4][ 5][ 6][ 7][ 8][ 9][10][11][12][13][14][15][16]
```

Here is my shoddy and not functioning code so far:

```
int index_counter; /* Control variable to count through index      */

printf("\n   Search Path: ");

if (search_target <= array[last_index])
{
   for (index_counter = 0; array[index_counter] <= search_target;
        index_counter++)
   {
      printf("[%2d]", index_counter);
   }
   *target_index = index_counter - 1;
}
else
{
   printf("[%2d]", last_index);
   *target_index = last_index;
}
return search_target == array[*target_index] ? 1 : 0;
```

I narrowed the problem down to the for loop in the first if statement. Index_counter is incrementing 17 times, when it should be only incrementing 15 times. I don't understand why it isn't working like it should.

Comment: There is a `return` statement at the end, so I am guessing this is part of the body of a function? What are `search_target` and `array` and `last_index`? Could you include the whole function in your post rather than just this part of the body?

Comment: Parameters passed into the function. search_target is the same as the target value entered in by the user, array is the array of items, and last_index is essentially the total number of items in the index.

Comment: "essentially"??

Comment: It's used to access the last item in the array[] index (It should be in the code?) So it is essentially the total number of items in the index. Hence the name last_index. The last item in the index.

Comment: Well, one problem is clear: there is nothing in the condition of your `for`-loop to stop the search when you arrive at the last element of the array.

Comment: That's already caught by the if-statement at the top of the code. If the statement fails, then C has a serious issue

Comment: Try replacing `<=` with `<` in `if (search_target <= array[last_index])`, or replacing `for (index_counter = 0; array[index_counter] <= search_target; index_counter++)` with `for (index_counter = 0; index_counter < last_index && array[index_counter] <= search_target; index_counter++)`

Comment: The issue is not with C ;) It is with your code.